# Where are the Logics and Data of the OBD System Stored?

Tags: can-bus, obd, scan-tool

I'm wondering if OBD Data is stored and processed on it's own board or integrated into other systems, or both. Or neither. Wikipedia just confused me further.

What I got out of the wiki is that OBD is a generic term for the complete system and the data that it parses; OBD II [and others] are your specific interface or bus... but, I dunno. I have a feeling I'm not understanding completely, and maybe overthinking it.

I'm reading up on BCM and ECU now, but not certain if that's the direction to go. My objective is just to understand the electrical systems of vehicles better. Messing with OBD seemed fun.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Thank you! I found this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OhShoU_E-0g

Comment: As I thought, I was completely mistaken as to what OBD2 was. Though this question was also misguided, it seems to answer mine in the same way: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/43100/obd-or-can-whats-mandatory-eu-and-us?rq=1